# Usando SELECT para listar informações

Tags: html

Preciso de uma ajudinha pra uma situação. Preciso listar informações dentro dos Estados. EX: Se eu clicar no Acre, eu preciso que ao clicar, surja uma caixinha com umas informações sobre o mesmo.
Mas eu não sei como fazer com que essas informações apareçam. Não quero usar php ou java, pois serão poucas informações.

Somente com html dá pra fazer isso? Tem algum site que explique? dei uma pesquisada e não achei.. Se alguém me ajudar, eu agradeço! :)

```
    <label class="estados">Selecione o estadopara exibir as informações que deseja.</label>
<select class="Test" name="tEst" id="estados">
<option value="Selecione"> SELECIONE</option>
<option value="ac"> Acre</option>
<option value="al"> Alagoas</option>
<option value="ap"> Amapá</option>                               
</select>
```

(E depois continua todos os estados.)

Comment: Você teria que utilizar algo com banco de dados para quando vc escolhesse "Acre" ele faria um Select no banco e retornaria para vc e você colocaria a informação na caixa.

Comment: Creio que seja impossível consegui fazer isso usando apenas HTML.

Comment: Eu já vi um exemplo desse código usando html, mas não me lembro em qual site.
Como são poucas informações, achei que só no html ajudaria.

Comment: Se você quiser usar só Javascript + HTML dá tranquilamente

Comment: @Sorack é complicado pois eu não entendo bem de java. Tem algum artigo que possa me mandar?

Comment: É `Javascript` só. Só do lado do navegador mesmo. Eu vou postar uma resposta como ficaria como método alternativo caso ninguém te de uma resposta com apenas HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi de sua pergunta, você que utilizar apenas o lado do `client`, então caso possa utilizar `Javascript`, como meio alternativo, eu te aconselho a utilizar [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) que resolveria de forma simples seu problema. Seu código ficaria assim:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('appEstados', []);

  angular
    .module('appEstados')
    .controller('EstadoController', EstadoController);

  EstadoController.$inject = [];

  function EstadoController() {
    var estado = this;
    estado.opcoes = [];

    iniciar();

    function iniciar() {
      estado.opcoes = [];
      estado.opcoes.push({nome: "Acre", informacoes: "O Acre é um estado que começa com A"});
      estado.opcoes.push({nome: "Alagoas", informacoes: "O Alagoas é um estado também que começa com A"});

      estado.seleciona = estado.opcoes[0];
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="appEstados">
  <div ng-controller="EstadoController as estado">
    <label class="estados">Selecione o estado para exibir as informações que deseja.</label>
    <select ng-options="opcao.nome for opcao in estado.opcoes" ng-model="estado.selecionado"></select>

    <br>
    <br>

    {{estado.selecionado.informacoes}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu super certo!
Só me tira uma dúvida, se eu quiser editar as informações, teria como? No caso, mudar fonte, tamanho da fonte e etc, no css. Eu teria que utilizar qual classe daí? Porque as informações estão no Java né.

Comment: @InezBoldrin você pode aplicar CSS normalmente, é só HTML + Javascript. Você sabe fazer isso?

Comment: Sim, sei usar o CSS. Porém, a classe das informações que eu não sei qual é.

Comment: @InezBoldrin Eu não coloquei classe nenhuma, mas é só você alterar o HTML e colocar ^^

Comment: Eu fiz a alteração que eu precisava. Eu usei os estados como exemplo, para simplificar a questão. Mas estou fazendo com bairros, mas ainda sim contendo informações, sendo que nesse caso são de estabelecimentos, endereços e telefones.

Comment: E por exemplo, tenho que colocar duas informações dentro do mesmo Bairro, é o mesmo procedimento?

Comment: Isso mesmo, é só adicionar mais uma propriedade e outro local pra mostrar a informação

Comment: Então se no Bairro Botafogo eu quiser adicionar duas informações diferentes, eu teria que fazer o seguinte:

 bairro.opcoes.push({nome: "Botafogo", informacoes: É um bairro da Zona Sul da cidade do  RJ." E para adicionar a segunda informação, deveria ser: ", informacoes: "Onde se localiza o clube , Botafogo de Futebol e Regatas"}); ou tem alguma forma de fazer direto mas com quebra de linha? Tô meio perdida rs

Comment: @InezBoldrin você faria o seguinte `bairro.opcoes.push({nome: "Botafogo", informacoes: É um bairro da Zona Sul da cidade do RJ.", informacoes2: "Onde se localiza o clube , Botafogo de Futebol e Regatas"});`. E no HTML colocaria um `{{bairro.selecionado.informacoes2}}` onde você quer que apareça a segunda parte das informações. Quebra de linha é `\n` no texto.

Comment: Ah entendi! De certa foram meu raciocínio não foi tão errado. Obrigada!!!

Comment: você me ajudou a solucionar essa questão, porém a execução do código não está mais como antes. Teria como me ajudar?

Comment: Você pode criar uma nova questão com suas novas dúvidas para que possa sana-la completamente